# serving RequireJS main optimized file as a static asset from NGINX

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nginx, requirejs

I hear that you are better off serving static assets from NGINX or another server and not your Node.js application server.

I have a single-page application that, in production mode, serves only one optimized .js file from the index page, and from there on out the server just serves a JSON API to the client.

So from what I gather it would be a good idea to serve that one .js file from a static assets server.

Here is the first and only HTML file I serve when the client hits the URL of my app:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <!-- stylesheets-->
    <link href="/static/css/bootstrap/bootstrap-notify.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

<main>
    <div name="main-div" id="main-div-id"></div>
</main>

<% if(env === 'development') {%>

<script data-main="/static/app/js/main" src="/static/vendor/require.js"></script>

<% } else { %> 

<script src="/static/app/optimized/optimized.js"></script>

<% } %>


</body>
</html>
```

so my question is, how do I configure this standard application to require the optimized.js file from NGINX? is it as simple as putting the URL of the NGINX server asset? anyone have a good example of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your NGINX server is on the same server that your app is running, there's no need to change the  urls, you can use this config in your /etc/nginx/conf.d/yoursitename.conf  for tell to NGINX to find the static files direct from a folder instead of passing through the nodejs app router.

```
upstream someservice.somedomain.com {
    # port where you have the app runing on the machine
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name someservice.somedomain.com someservice.somedomain;
    client_max_body_size 10M;

    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|pdf|txt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|js|flv|swf|html|htm|ps|woff|svg)$ {
      expires modified +7d;
      # static files path
      root   /home/projectfolder/public/;
    }

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

      proxy_pass http://someservice.somedomain.com/;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }
 }
```